# Resolution of transitive dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

## Information

I have two modules in the project - the app's module (`app`) and a library (`mylibrary`). The `app` module depends on `mylibrary` and also includes `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1`, which allows me to use APIs such as `registerForActivityResult`. This API is provided from the chain of transitive dependencies: `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1` -> `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6` -> `androidx:activity.activity:1.5.1`

However, `mylibrary` module depends on `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0`. These libraries transitively add `androidx.fragment:fragment` of version `1.0.0`, which doesn't have `registerForActivityResult`. In this case, the `FragmentActivity` in the `androidx:fragment` dependency is inherited not from `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity`, but from `androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity` provided transitively with `androidx.core:core:1.2.0` from the aforementioned Play Services libraries.

#### Android Studio Version

Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335, built on September 30, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.6.8
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Registry:
external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.intellij.plugins.macoskeymap (213.5744.3)
com.intellij.marketplace (213.7172.48)
com.thoughtworks.gauge (213.5744.125)

## Problem

If I include `mylibrary` to the `app` module, the `registerForActivityResult` method is highlighted red as if it can't be resolved. However, the project compiles and runs as expected.

## Question

Is there a way to fix this issue? Even though the project compiles, code completion in AS doesn't work when I try to use such APIs like `registerForActivityResult` or `by viewModels`. I tried to exclude `androidx.activity` and `androidx.core` from the Play Services libraries, but with no result.

## Example

You can see the problem on [the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDbqH.jpg) or fetch the [example project](https://github.com/shamilovstas/TransitiveDependency)